# A non-greedy Perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I need to write a script which does the following:

```
$ cat testdata.txt
this is my file containing data
for checking pattern matching with a patt on the back!
only one line contains the p word.

$ ./mygrep5 pat th testdata.txt
this is my file containing data
for checking PATTERN MATCHING WITH a PATT ON THe back!
only one line contains the p word.
```

I have been able to print the line which is amended with the "a" capitalized as well. I have no idea how to only take what is needed.

I have been messing around (below is my script so far) and all I manage to return is the "PATT ON TH" part.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump 'pp';

my ($f, $s, $t) = @ARGV;
my @output_lines;

open(my $fh, '<', $t);

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ($line =~ /$f/ && $line =~ /$s/) {
        $line =~ s/($f.+?$s)/$1/g;
        my $sub_phrase = uc $1;
        $line =~ s/$1/$sub_phrase/g;
        print $line;
    }
    #else {
    #       print $line;
    #}
}

close($fh);
```

which returns: "for checking pattern matching with a PATT ON THe back!"

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Is the output above what you get, or what you want to get? Do you want the `a` to be capitalised or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to capitalize from `pat` to `th` except for instances of `a` surrounded by spaces. The easiest way is to uppercase the whole thing, and then fix any instances of `A` surrounded by spaces.

```
sub capitalize {
    my $s = shift;
    my $uc = uc($s);
    $uc =~ s/ \s \K A (?=\s) /a/xg;
    return $uc;
}

s{ ( \Q$f\E .* \Q$s\E ) }{ capitalize($1) }xseg;
```

The downside is that will replacing any existing `A` surrounded by spaces with `a`. The following is more complicated, but it doesn't suffer from that problem:

```
sub capitalize {
    my $s = shift;
    my @parts = $s =~ m{ \G ( \s+ | \S+ ) }xg;
    for (@parts) {
       $_ = uc($_) if $_ ne "a";
    }

    return join('', @parts);
}

s{ ( \Q$f\E .* \Q$s\E ) }{ capitalize($1) }xseg;
```

---

The rest of the code can be simplified:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub capitalize { ... }

my $f = shift;
my $s = shift;

while (<>) {
    s{ ( \Q$f\E .* \Q$s\E ) }{ capitalize($1) }xseg;
    print;
}
```

Comment: This one obvs also worked - thank you for the submission

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, "So you want to do X? Here's how!" is a rhetorical construct, never an actual question. Whatever, no reason to revert. But no need to tell someone with 311k that SO isn't a forum. That was a bit patronising, eh? (Also not a question.)

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, Actually, I did need to fix it. You actually changed the wording into an implied question while claiming to do the opposite. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to match each sequence that starts with `pat` and ends with `th`, non-greedily, and uppercase that sequence, you can simply use an expression on the right side of your substitution:

```
$line =~ s/($f.+?$s)/uc($1)/eg;
```

And that's it.

Comment: I was on the right path - I was doing something like this previously - but it wouldn't work (was unaware of "eg"). So I gave up on it and went for more code :(!!!! Thanks for the help

Comment: `e` means "evaluate the right hand part as an expression", rather than just a string. There are many more useful flags, you may want to check out `perlop` and `perlre` for details.